# Pandas map column based on number range from a dict

Tags: python, pandas

Input dataframe:

```
  file_id       filename
  30140       WS52RN-300-7750460312963...
  30730       DMX5N4H-336-7G5082A_15089528977...
  31215       114-403CBC_1508935183409.mp4
  32000       VQCYSR-300-84L7F5D9_1508937725363...
  32648       69HM-336-6262906_48508952353171.mp4
```

Dict:

```
h={28: [30138, 30636], 29: [30637, 31117], 30: [31118, 31616], 31: [31617, 32115], 32: [32151, 32649]}
```

I need to create the column `file_num` based on the dict above.
If a file_id is between the `value` range then the key becomes the `file_num`

Expected output:

```
  file_id       filename                                  file_num
  30140       WS52RN-300-7750460312963...                  28
  30141       DMX5N4H-336-7G5082A_15089528977...           28
  31215       114-403CBC_1508935183409.mp4                 30
  32000       VQCYSR-300-84L7F5D9_1508937725363...         31
  32648       69HM-336-6262906_48508952353171.mp4          32
```

Im trying to use some combination of map with `h` but I am not getting the results i need. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What happens if the `file_id` is out of range? For example, there is nothing in the dictionary between `32115` and `32151`.

Comment: `[next(k for k, [i, j] in h.items() if i <= x <= j) for x in df.file_id]` Is a naive solution.  Unfortunately it's `O(m*n)`

Comment: @chrisaycock the `file_id` will always be in one of the keys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `IntervalIndex`

```
matchdf=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(h,'index').reset_index()
matchdf.index=pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(left=matchdf[0],right=matchdf[1],closed= 'both')
df['New']=matchdf.loc[df.file_id]['index'].values
df
Out[128]: 
   file_id                              filename  New
0    30140           WS52RN-300-7750460312963...   28
1    30730    DMX5N4H-336-7G5082A_15089528977...   29
2    31215          114-403CBC_1508935183409.mp4   30
3    32000  VQCYSR-300-84L7F5D9_1508937725363...   31
4    32648   69HM-336-6262906_48508952353171.mp4   32
```

Comment: @ksooklall yw :-) man , happy coding :-) vote for your question

Comment: I seem to be getting a `raise KeyError` when trying the loc even thought the columns are in both dataframes

Comment: @ksooklall there may have a over lap , or some of the value do not exit in the any range

Comment: I know all values exist with in the range since the dict goes well beyond the max file num. There is a lot of overlap, multiple `file_ids` will go to a `file_num`

Comment: @ksooklall when there is overlap , what you want to do it , is so I will recommend O(m*n) method show up in the comment

Comment: I don't understand, it worked perfectly fine with overlap (with the given `h`), I am just using a bigger `h` and it's failing

Comment: @ksooklall ummm, I think I am kind of lost here, since I do not have the data in hand ..sorry about that man